# How do I use the rewrite rule to replace the `.php` wth `/`

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I use the rewrite rule to replace the `.php` wth `/`

For example:

`search.php?k=background`   to   `search/?k=background`

What I have so far is:

```
RewriteRule ^search/?k=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ search.php/?k=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the query string from your rewrite rule, that gets appended automatically:

```
RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
#Rule applies only when the script is search.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*search\.php.*$
#Query will be automatically appended to search/
RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.com/search/ [L]
```

Will redirect:

`http://mydomain.com/search.php?k=background` to

`http://mydomain.com/search/?k=background`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php(.*)$ $1/$2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the thing is, it should rewrite only for the `search.php` not for all. Moreover the above example doesn't work.